# attribute ValidateInput(false) not work in IAuthorizationFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-attributes

When I edit my username as html tag or xml tag it will generate exception like:

`potentially dangerous Request.Form` in `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["key"];`

But i have mension `[ValidateInput(false)]` why it's not handled in  `MyFilter` class.

---

Following is my code:

**FilterConfig.cs**:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new MyFilter()); 

    }
}
```

**MyFilter.cs**:

```
public class MyFilter: IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        SessionDataManagement.BackupCurrent();
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        string requestID = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["key"];
    }
}
```

**MyController.cs**:

```
public class CompanyController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Edit(Class1 objCompany)
    {
        //Logic
    }
}
```

**Class1.cs**:

```
public class Class1
{ 
    [Required]
    [AllowHtml]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

}
```